# why my animations are not proper and image loading is taking more time in some of the images?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

```
public class LoadImageActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView image_view;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        image_view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        me m1=new me();
        m1.execute("http://wallbase1.org/thumbs/rozne/thumb-499842.jpg");
        me m2=new me();
        m2.execute( "http://wallbase1.org/thumbs/rozne/thumb-637449.jpg"); 
        me m3=new me();
        m3.execute( "http://wallbase1.org/thumbs/rozne/thumb-2509834.jpg"); 
        me m4=new me();
        m4.execute( "http://wallbase1.org/thumbs/rozne/thumb-2501884.jpg"); 
        me m5=new me();
        m5.execute( "http://wallbase1.org/thumbs/rozne/thumb-2514440.jpg");
     };


     class me extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

        Bitmap b1;

        // private MainActivity m1;
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String...params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             try {

                  /* Open a new URL and get the InputStream to load data from it. */

                  URL aURL = new URL(params[0]);
                  URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                  conn.connect();
                  InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                  /* Buffered is always good for a performance plus. */
                  BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

                  /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */
                  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                  b1=bm;

                  bis.close();
                  is.close();

              } catch (IOException e) 
              {

                  Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remote Image Exception", e);

              }

           return null;
       }

    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            image_view.setImageBitmap(b1);
            Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(LoadImageActivity.this, R.anim.rotate);
         image_view.startAnimation(rotation);
    }
        }}
```

I am trying to show an image from internet by decoding it into bitmap,i want to show multiple images from multiple urls.Is there any better way of implementing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duration of a download depends on a lot of different stuff. You currently spawn 5 AsyncTasks and there is no guarantee that the order of delivery/execution will be the same order you spawned them. It is easily possible that the fifth image might be the first you received and this would result in a totally wrong order. So you should download *all* images first, possibly with just one AsyncTask. After that and if that succeeded, you should start the animation and switch between the images.

Comment: you are right i have no order for the execution of my threads but how can i solve this

Comment: as I mentioned, download all images in the background method and start your animation in the onPostExecute().

Comment: Please read my answer again. I suggested that you use one AsyncTask to download all images. So instead of providing one URL to your task, provide a list.

Answer (score 0):

There're several better ways of doing it and all of them are far more complex than your code. But you do have a good start.

This video form Google I/O have some good techniques for image, check around 4:40 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbQb1PVjfqM

It takes different times because they are different images with probably different sizes.

Please post your XML `R.anim.rotate` code so someone can try to check why the animation is not working.

Comment: check the video, it explains the usage of the LruCache, great class for that.